# How to split a string by ':' character in bash/zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, string

I am searching for a way to split a string (variable) by `:` character, in a compatible way between bash and zsh.

From different sources, I found the following command:

```
str="part1=part2=part3"
parts=(${(@s:=:)str})
echo ${#parts[@]}
```

However, I could not find the way to escape `:` for this same sequence

```
parts=(${(@s:::)str})  #Not working
parts=(${(@s:\::)str}) #Not working
```

For bash, I found this:

```
parts=(${str//:/ })
```

Which works, but is not really compatible. I could use the following line to discriminate the shell:

```
if [ -z "$(ps -p $$| grep zsh)" ]; then
    echo "This is bash (Use bash solution here)"
else
    echo "This is zsh (Use Zsh solution here)"
fi
```

But maybe some alternative solution is compatible? Any working solution is already a win.

Comment: How come that you need to do it the same way in both shells? Don't you know what interpreter you're using?

Comment: I need to do a script which is compatible with both shells, because I know both will be used.

Comment: Huh, that's like asking for doing it the same way in Perl and Python, because the script will be executed by both. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kusalananda There are projects like `rbenv` and `rvm` that present themselves to the user as shell functions, in rbenv's case to be able to tie a ruby environment to an existing shell session. Given that bash and zsh are probably the most common shells in use by a wide margin and that their syntax are very compatible between each other (*a lot* more than Perl's and Python's), I think it makes a lot of sense for projects like that to try to be compatible with both.

Comment: @Kusalananda There are also projects that add some shell initialization like how Gnome's VTE [adds a file in /etc/profile.d/ compatible with both bash and zsh to set the window title to include the working directory of the shell as it changes](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/blob/master/src/vte.sh.in).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `:` there is any arbitrary character:

You can use:

```
parts=(${(s/:/)str})
```

Some common character pairs are also supported like:

```
parts=(${(s[:])str})
```

If you're going to use the `@` flag to preserve empty elements, then you need to
quote:

```
parts=("${(@s[:])str}")
```

Otherwise `@` makes no difference.

If it's to process variables like `$PATH`/`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`... see also `typeset -T` which *ties* an array variable to a scalar variable:

```
$ typeset -T str str_array
$ str='a::b'
$ typeset -p str
typeset -T str str_array=( a '' b )
```

`zsh` does tie `$path` to `$PATH` by default (like in `csh`/`tcsh`).

bash's

```
parts=(${str//:/ })
```

Is wrong as it applies split+glob after having replaced `:` with SPC.

You'd want:

```
IFS=:            # split on : instead of default SPC TAB NL
set -o noglob    # disable glob
parts=( $str"" ) # split+glob (leave expansion unquoted), preserve trailing
                 # empty part.
```

That code would also work in `zsh`, if it was in `sh` or `ksh` emulation mode. If your goal is to write code compatible to both `bash` and `zsh`, you may want to write it using ksh syntax and make sure that `zsh` is put in `ksh` emulation (possibly only locally to some function) when interpreting it.

To test whether the shell is `bash` or `zsh`, you'd test for the presence of the `$BASH_VERSION`/`$BASH_VERSINFO` or `$ZSH_VERSION` variables.

```
split() { # args: string delimiter result_var
  if
    [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] &&
      autoload is-at-least &&
      is-at-least 5.0.8 # for ps:$var:
  then
    eval $3'=("${(@ps:$2:)1}")'
  elif
    [ "$BASH_VERSINFO" -gt 4 ] || {
      [ "$BASH_VERSINFO" -eq 4 ] && [ "${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}" -ge 4 ]
      # 4.4+ required for "local -"
    }
  then
    local - IFS="$2"
    set -o noglob
    eval "$3"'=( $1"" )'
  else
    echo >&2 "Your shell is not supported"
    exit 1
  fi
}

split "$str" : parts
```

Comment: This is great, although beware if bash is invoked from zsh, or vice versa, it seems for me that the environment variables linger, making this shell detection confused.