# Why is echo needed for IFS to take effect in zsh?

Tags: zsh, array, echo

I am trying to read members of the `PATH` into an array using zsh 5.8. I am used to Bash, where the following normally works:

```bsh
IFS=: p=($PATH)
```

However with zsh, this actually gives me an array with only one item. If I write instead:

```bsh
IFS=: p=($(echo $PATH))
```

then I get the correct number of elements. Why is that?

Comment: If you're looking for `$PATH` as an array, you can use `$path` in zsh, see https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html (search for "path <S> <Z> (PATH <S>)").

Comment: @Wieland Thanks a lot for the tip! I'm still curious about the difference between bash and zsh in the specific example I posted, regardless of using the `$PATH` variable or something else like `foo='a:b c:d'` (should yield 3 items); if you feel like writing an answer, that would be great :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because zsh doesn't do word splitting to parameter expansions by default, unlike POSIXy shells. It does for command substitutions, so the round trip via one "fixes" it for you. But it's still far from the right thing to do in zsh, and the combination of `echo` and command substitution could even mangle the data in some cases.

In zsh, you could use `$=PATH` to ask for word splitting, or use the more proper solutions presented here: [How to split a string by ':' character in bash/zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/614299/170373)

Also in case of `PATH`, it's tied to the array variable `path` in zsh by default, so you don't need to do anything to access it as an array.

---

<sub>(In `IFS=: p=($PATH)`, the unquoted expansion would also be subject to filename generation or globbing, so if any of the paths in `PATH` happen to contain globbing characters (`*?[]`, maybe others), the results may not be what you want. Round-tripping via a command substitution and `echo` would also remove any trailing newlines, and (depending on `echo`) might also mangle backslashes.)</sub>

Comment: Stephane's answer in the link you shared is pretty scary stuff.. but thanks for the link and for the answer!

Comment: @JonathanH, mmm. Zsh can be a bit... hard to read with all the one-character modifiers. But that `parts=(${(s/:/)str})` is pretty clear still. Within the array assignment we have `${(s/:/)str}` which is just a parameter expansion like `${str}` or `$str`, but with the `s/:/` modifier that tells it to split on `:` (`s` for split, I suppose, and the `/`s are just separators, parens around to mark it as a modifier). It's cleaner to give the separator there, where it's needed, since changes to `IFS` could affect the rest of the script too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I guess I scare easily! Still, this looks like voodoo to me: `eval $3'=("${(@ps:$2:)1}")'`

Comment: @JonathanH, yes, he's going all in on being generic there. You'd only need that `eval` trick if you want to be able to put the elements in an array variable of an arbitrary name.

Comment: Great answer but maybe it doesn't make it clear enough that `IFS=: p=($PATH)` in bash is definitely wrong, and using `IFS=: p=($(echo $PATH))` in zsh is even more wrong.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm sure you are right, but I don't understand how `IFS=: p=($PATH)` in bash is different from the codeblock in the middle of your linked answer, if I know there are no glob patterns, and that it is not empty? Would you recommend using `typeset -T` instead (and would that be limited to the scope of a function)?

Comment: @JonathanH, you may happen to be in a special case where the bugs in that incorrect code are not hit, but that doesn't make it any less wrong. You wouldn't want to use that code in a script, and if you advertise that code  in an answer here, that should come along with a *if you can guarantee the variable doesn't contain wildcard characters and doesn't end in an empty element*. Or use the correct `a=("${(@s[:])s}")` (or `typeset -T`) in zsh or `IFS=:; set -o noglob; a=($s'')` in bash/POSIX.